# How do I solve a pair of simultaneous equations where one is a modulus function?

Tags: functions

The question is as follows:
$y=x+4, 
y=|x^2 - 16|$

Currently, I understand how to solve basic modulus functions (as per IGCSE Additional Mathematics). However, I'm stumped on this question because I do not know how to solve simultaneous equations of this kind, and there are no examples for me to refer to.

I would appreciate if anyone answers this! It would really help my summer studies.
This is also my first post on any Stack forum, and it definitely won't be my last.

Comment: Draw graph or solve by using cases.

Comment: This would be easier to solve if you split your `abs` function in 2 parts. for -4 < x < 4, the second equation would be (16 - x^2) else (x^2-16) Now you can try solving between these ranges.

Comment: For the graph approach see https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ekxljhyvuw

Comment: For a shortcut, start with $\,x+4 = |x+4|\,|x-4|\,$.

Comment: The Exercise that I'm doing that involves this question comes before all the graphing part, so I have to do it with just calculation. One thing I've noticed thanks to the comments and after looking at the question for a fair bit is that it is actually a trick question. Everything is just the same but the simultaneous part is there to screw with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It schould be clear that $x=-4$ is a solution of

$$(*) \quad \,x+4 = |x+4|\,|x-4|\,.$$

If $x \ne -4$ we get

$$ \frac{x+4}{|x+4|}=|x-4|.$$

The RHS is $ \ge 0$, hence we see that $x+4 >0.$ Thus we derive

$$|x-4|=1.$$

Conclusion: the equation $(*)$ has the solutions

$$-4,3,5.$$

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thank you! I just need to see how I got 4 (instead of -4) though as one of the solutions.

Comment: Also, what is RHS?

Comment: RHS = right hand side (of the equation).